# I dont understand how this is deciding what is and isn't a prime number

Tags: java

Very new to programming here, trying to get my head around how this is works and I just cannot seem to do it, spent a good while staring at this one.

code already works, I Just do not fully understand.

````
class PrimeNum{
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a;
int b;
boolean isprime;

System.out.println("this is a program listing prime numbers up to 100");

for(a = 2; a < 100; a++){

for(b=2; b <= a/b; b++) 

  ```if((a%b) == 0) isprime = false;```

  if(isprime)
  System.out.println(a + " is prime.");
  }
 }
}
````

I think that i understand both for lines, please correct me If I am wrong.

Am I correct in saying that, if a is less than 100, increment
if b is less than or = to a/b then increment again which it always will be

the line that i don't understand is highlighted in particular, what is the need for the ==0?

I just cannot seem to grasp the concept that is happening here and how its figuring out what is and isn't prime.

Comment: Grade school math. `if ((a % b)` - if the remainder of (a / b) `== 0` then `a` is divisible by `b` (and thus `a` is **not** prime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we'll start up:

```
public static void main(String[] args){..}
```

This is the main method which every Java program should have. You'll get to learn user-defined methods, but that's for later;

We'll skip the variable declaration...

```
for(a = 2; a < 100; a++){...
}
```

This first loop gets you a number for deciding for its prime being...

```
for(b=2; b <= a/b; b++) 

  if((a%b) == 0)
 isprime = false;
```

Probably b is for division of a...

So if you execute this 6 times for number 2,
it'll go that way, if the remainder got on dividing 2 is zero or not.
Here, it is till 100. And the logic is such that the divisor will be less than or equal to dividend(b <= a/b).

SO a%b == 0 means that if a is divided by b and if remainder is zero, then it is a prime 'cause prime numbers have no factors rather than 1 and the number itself.

Hope you're clear about this.

SO keep calm, code and HIT A UPVOTE OR COMMENT IF SOMETHING IS WRONG!

Comment: Thanks for that, now I finally understand what a%b == 0 is doing, much appreciated.